# sqlite get row first by id then display the rest order by time

Tags: android, sqlite

Welcome guys,
I have method contains cursor and its job is to retrieve data from database.
When I pass id to the method I want the row which has this id to be selected and displayed first then continue showing other rows ordered by time field :)
how?

Comment: You mean you want something like "SELECT * from (Table) where [id] > {0} order by time?

Comment: No, I mean select by id = specificID and then start selecting other rows ordered by time

Comment: Try a union but it would not be eficient where the first select has the id clause and second union neglects the id and considers time

Comment: Cannot use order by case ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use two SELECTs combined by a UNION. The 1st gets the single row by id. The 2nd gets all the other rows not equal to the id. By hardcoding a 'sort' value in each SELECT, you can order by time whilst also forcing the row from the 1st SELECT to the top.

For example you should be able to use SQL of this form in a rawQuery:

```
SELECT _id, time, 0 AS sort
FROM my_table
WHERE _id = ?

UNION ALL

SELECT _id, time, 1 AS sort
FROM my_table
WHERE _id <> ?

ORDER BY sort, time
```

EDIT:

As the error says in your comments, terms in the ORDER BY need to match columns in the result set. So you need to move the CASE to the select. So something of the form:

```
SELECT * , 0 AS sort, CASE WHEN date(note_notification) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sort2
FROM NotesTable WHERE note_id == 26
UNION ALL
SELECT * , 1 AS sort, CASE WHEN date(note_notification) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sort2
FROM NotesTable
ORDER BY sort, sort2, note_notification
```

If that still does not resolve your issue, please update your question as CL. suggests, illustrating your source data and the results set you are seeking to achieve from it.

Comment: Yes, I believe you can.

Comment: here is my code
`c = QNotesDB.rawQuery("SELECT * , 0 AS sort FROM " + DATABASE_NOTETABLE + " WHERE " + NOTE_ROWID + " == " + noteIntID + " UNION ALL SELECT * , 1 AS sort FROM " + DATABASE_NOTETABLE + " ORDER BY sort, (CASE WHEN date(" + NOTE_NOTIFICATION
     + ") IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), " + NOTE_NOTIFICATION, null);
    `
and it gives me force close
all constants and vars are declared well

Comment: here is the log cat
`02-06 17:29:30.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 17:29:30.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ibrahim.radwan.qnotes/ibrahim.radwan.qnotes.ViewNotesActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 2nd ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set: , while compiling: SELECT * , 0 AS sort FROM NotesTable WHERE note_id == 26 UNION ALL SELECT * , 1 AS sort FROM NotesTable ORDER BY sort, (CASE WHEN date(note_notification) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), note_notification
`

Comment: @hemoali What is that CASE for? Edit your question to show what you actually want.

Comment: this case for showing not null values first and then show null values at the end :)